Stargazer Table Causes PDF Knit Error: '! You can't use `\relax' after \the
I'm encountering an error when knitting my R Markdown file to a PDF. The error message is as follows:
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> ...ort/tbl/leaders/begin_args_int 

After some troubleshooting, I traced the issue to the stargazer table in my R Markdown file. Here's the relevant code:
stargazer(
  m3, m4,
  title = "title",
  align = TRUE,
  header = FALSE,
  dep.var.labels = c("Model 1"),
  type = stargazer_opt,  # Explicitly ensure LaTeX output
  star.cutoffs = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001),  # Define custom significance levels
  no.space = F  # Remove extra spacing
)

Interestingly, adding the following option to stargazer resolves the error:
omit.table.layout = "l",

However, this workaround feels like it's merely hiding the underlying issue rather than addressing the root cause.
Questions:

What could be causing this error in the stargazer output when knitting to PDF?
Is there a better solution to fix this error without omitting parts of the table layout?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.
I expected to Knit my R Markdown file to a PDF, I however recieved the following error message:
! You can't use `\relax' after \the.
<recently read> ...ort/tbl/leaders/begin_args_int 


You should show us the m3 and m4 inputs (or fake ones that also generate the error). Also put together a minimal R Markdown document holding everything. Without those, we can't reproduce the issue, so that makes it much harder to debug.
